# Pandoc Latex to markdown non-html figures/links

Tags: pandoc

I use the following Pandoc command to convert Latex to markdown: `pandoc -s latex.tex -o gfm.md -t gfm`

I have any figures or links, pandoc converts these to HTML elements rather than markdown elements. Because GFM is extended markdown, it should have support for these elements. How would I force pandoc to produce non-html elements.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658880) points to using `-t markdown` as a solution, but this does not work either